# Swift pods cannot yet be integrated as static libraries FirebaseCoreInternal-library

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, cocoapods

I am building an app by Flutter. I got this error message when doing "`pod install`" or "`pod install --repo-update`" or "`pod update`" and the pod install failed and stopped.

The error message:

> [!] The following Swift pods cannot yet be integrated as static
> libraries:
>
> The Swift pod `FirebaseCoreInternal-library` depends upon
> `GoogleUtilities-library`, which does not define modules. To opt into
> those targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import
> them from Swift when building as static libraries), you may set
> `use_modular_headers!` globally in your Podfile, or specify
> `:modular_headers => true` for particular dependencies.

My Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '11.0'

...

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

...
```

Comment: Same issue when I upgrade my Xcode and Firebase version. Got any idea to solve this issue? I am trying to use another method to import firebase (xcode package manager), not sure if it works or not.

Comment: You can try the steps below, they helped me

Comment: https://dev.to/matthewzruiz/firebase-the-following-swift-pods-cannot-yet-be-integrated-as-static-libraries-b59

Answer (score 274, accepted):

You may not need to use `use_frameworks!` or `use_modular_headers!` because it's getting conflict with use_flipper

You can add the following without using them in ios/Podfile:

```
  platform :ios, '12.4'
  ...
  ...
  
  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true

  #....add any library need headers
```

Best

Comment: Doing this I get `target has transitive dependencies that include statically linked binaries`

Comment: I am using `use_frameworks` and this solved the stated issue for me, as well as an issue with Firebase: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/6403#issue-1308184812

Comment: You may want to remove `FirebaseCoreInternal` for version 10.x and above.

Comment: Congratulations on giving better responses than GPT-4. I couldn't have solved my problem without you.

Comment: Great works locally, but when is generating an EAS build? how can we resolve it?

Answer (score 107):

For newest version of `firebase 15.1.1` with `react-native 0.69.1` no need to enable `use_frameworks` because it will lead to errors in deploying in real devices

So you just need to add the `firebase` modulars and set headers to true.

```
     pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
     pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
     pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
     $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
```

And keep using flipper

```
  use_flipper!()
```

I tested it on both Android and IOS on real devices and it works great!

Here is what my Podfile looks like

```js
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
    require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
    
    platform :ios, '12.4'
    install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false
    
    target 'myApp' do
      config = use_native_modules!
      flags = get_default_flags()
        
      pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
      pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
      pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
      $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
    
    
      use_react_native!(
        :path => config[:reactNativePath],
        # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
        :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
        :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
        # An absolute path to your application root.
        :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
      )
    
      target 'myAppTests' do
        inherit! :complete
        # Pods for testing
      end
    
      # Enables Flipper.
      #
      # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
      # you should disable the next line.
      use_flipper!()
    
      post_install do |installer|
        react_native_post_install(installer)
        __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
      end
    end
```

### -

- 

**UPDATED 20/Jul**

If you wanted to use rich content notifications like notifications with images. Following [this article](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration/#step-2---add-target-to-the-podfile) by firebase will ask you to enable `use_frameworks` as well so my solution for that is to use `modular_headers => true` for the following packages

```
target 'richNotification' do
    pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging', :modular_headers => true
    pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
end
```

**NOTE:** Make sure `richNotification` target is at the bottom of the `podfile`. see below how my final `podfile` looks like

```js
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '12.4'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

target 'MyApp' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  flags = get_default_flags()

#     use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
  $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
  # Flags change depending on the env values.


  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end

target 'richNotification' do
    pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging', :modular_headers => true
    pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
end
```

I tested it on both Android and IOS, it works great!!

**For Testing**
Send the following JSON data to `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` as a"POST", and make sure to put in the headers `"mutable-content": "1",` See the screenshot below

```
{
        "to": " Put here your mobile fcm token ",
        "notification": {
            "title": "You have received a new request",
            "body": "Radiohead - Street Spirit (Fade Out)",
            "content_available" : "true",
            "priority" : "high",
            "sound":"defualt",
            "image": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/LCJblaUkkfc/hq720.jpg"
        },
        "android": {
          "priority": "high",
          "notification": {
            "imageUrl": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3mP3mJDL2k"
          }
        },
        "apns": {
          "payload": {
            "aps": {
              "mutable-content": "1",
              "content-available": "true",
            },
            "imageUrl": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/panR4xwt0wM/hqdefault.jpg",
            "fcm_options": {
              "imageUrl": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/panR4xwt0wM/hqdefault.jpg"
            }
          },
          "headers": {
            "mutable-content": "1",
            "apns-push-type": "background",
            "apns-priority": "5", 
            "apns-topic": "com.paidtabs" 
          }
        },
        "webpush": {
          "headers": {
            "image": "https://koenig-media.raywenderlich.com/uploads/2021/01/good_news_petsicon.png"
          }
        },
        "data":{
          "passingDataToApp" : "Mario",
          "body" : "great match!",
          "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
        }
      }
```

Headers look like
[image: headers]

Comment: you sir are a legend, we need more people like you around here!

Comment: YOU ARE A FREAKING LEGEND MY GUY, I KEPT TYPING THE POD 'firebase'... stuff into terminal, my problem would've been fixed 4 days ago if people posted their podfile snippet. THANK YOU

Comment: Is the advice to remove `use_frameworks!` suitable for Flutter (not React-Native)? Is there any documentation that explains what's going on with this?

Comment: Legend ... You are a legend :) I just spent 3 days find solution ... but it is a common thing.

Comment: Integrating Firebase in 2023, I needed to add these: `pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreExtension', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseInstallations', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleDataTransport', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'nanopb', :modular_headers => true`.

Answer (score 29):

pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true;

add this line to podfile

Comment: Thanks! Adding only this line was sufficient

Comment: This worked to solve my immediate problem but then did ultimately have to add the same thing for Firebase and FirebaseCore for other reasons.

Answer (score 27):

This worked for me too. @virluz just adding to your answer

Version of firebase 16.5 with react-native 70.5

Just add

```
pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true;
```

Between below code :

```
flags = get_default_flags()

    pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true;


  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
```

After that you can run

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Answer (score 19):

Removing `use_frameworks` because is conflicting with `use_flipper` and adding all this libs worked for me

```
  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true  
  pod 'FirebaseStorageInternal', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreExtension', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseAppCheckInterop', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseAuthInterop', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseMessagingInterop', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GTMSessionFetcher', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseAppCheckInterop', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseAuthInterop', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
```

**Heads up!** `FirebaseFunctions-h.swift` and `FirebaseStorage-h.swift` requires `use_frameworks`, so probably you may have an error with these files. Perhaps you may prefer use `axios` or similar lib to invoke your endpoint api and/or `aws s3` to save your file instead.

Comment: Yup - after a day of attempts, the above worked. Honestly upgrading deps for ios is such a chore.

Answer (score 14):

### ❗️ React Native developers:

I asked the maintainers of `react-native-firebase` about the solutions found here and they said **the app will eventually break** with these workarounds as modules are converted to Swift. `FirebaseFunctions-h.swift` and `FirebaseStorage-h.swift` already won't work. Here's the copy pasted answer:

> that's an unsupportable workaround to avoid use_frameworks, it is temporarily working for you at best, does not work already if you use storage or functions modules, and other modules will stop working as they fully convert to Swift. I strongly discourage anyone from using that.
>
> The correct solution is to incorporate use_frameworks and drop dependencies that don't support it or work in those repos that you cannot drop such that it is supported

Original answer: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/6594#issuecomment-1303612795

**EDIT:** Here's also an official discussion from the React Native community: https://github.com/react-native-community/discussions-and-proposals/discussions/546#discussioncomment-4168642

Comment: A little late to the party, but eventually how did you end up solving this issue? Because if the most up voted solution isn't a good solution and use_frameworks isn't compatible with Flipper, what's the solution then? :(

Comment: @dianaqqq Update React Native to get a better debugger. Expo has even a better debugging experience. Flipper is being deprecated: https://github.com/react-native-community/discussions-and-proposals/pull/641

Answer (score 11):

None of the previously suggested solutions worked for me (I also use Expo), however, adding the following snippet to `app.config.js` solved it for me:

1. Run `npx expo install expo-build-properties`
2. In `app.config.js` add: **<<<< CRITICAL STEP** [Referenced here](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/firebase-analytics/#additional-configuration-for-ios)

```
 plugins: [
      "@react-native-firebase/app",
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          ios: {
            useFrameworks: "static",
          },
        },
      ],
```

3. My Podfile

```
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"`), "scripts/autolinking")
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"`), "scripts/react_native_pods")
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/package.json')"`), "native_modules")

require 'json'
podfile_properties = JSON.parse(File.read(File.join(__dir__, 'Podfile.properties.json'))) rescue {}

platform :ios, podfile_properties['ios.deploymentTarget'] || '12.4'
install! 'cocoapods',
  :deterministic_uuids => false

target 'ProjectName' do
  use_expo_modules!
  config = use_native_modules!

#   use_frameworks! :linkage => podfile_properties['ios.useFrameworks'].to_sym if podfile_properties['ios.useFrameworks']

  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true  
  pod 'FirebaseStorageInternal', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreExtension', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseAppCheckInterop', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseAuthInterop', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseMessagingInterop', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GTMSessionFetcher', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseAppCheckInterop', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseAuthInterop', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled] || podfile_properties['expo.jsEngine'] == 'hermes',
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Dir.pwd}/.."
  )

  # Uncomment to opt-in to using Flipper
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work
  #
  # if !ENV['CI']
  use_flipper!()
  # end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)

    # This is necessary for Xcode 14, because it signs resource bundles by default
    # when building for devices.
    installer.target_installation_results.pod_target_installation_results
      .each do |pod_name, target_installation_result|
      target_installation_result.resource_bundle_targets.each do |resource_bundle_target|
        resource_bundle_target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
        end
      end
    end
  end

  post_integrate do |installer|
    begin
      expo_patch_react_imports!(installer)
    rescue => e
      Pod::UI.warn e
    end
  end
end
```

4. Don't forget to `cd ios && pod install`
5. Run your build, e.g. `eas build --platform ios --profile development --local`

RNFirebase versions

```
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "15.4",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "15.4",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "15.4",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "15.4",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "15.4",
    "@react-native-firebase/perf": "15.4",
```

Comment: This works for expo managed projects! also can be referenced here https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/6332#issuecomment-1172950523 if it is a managed project you do NOT need to deal with all the podfile stuff.

Comment: Managed workflow team user here. Doing steps 1 and 2 (removed "@react-native-firebase/app" and added quotes to ios and useFrameworks) resolved our EAS iOS build issue. Thank you

Comment: That's a valid answer, on top of those pods, from version `17.3.2` of `@react-native-firebase/*`, it'll ask you also for `FirebaseInstallations`, `GoogleDataTransport`, and `nanopb`.

Answer (score 10):

Regarding Expo managed, here's a config plugin that I've made, and works for me

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const generateCode = require('@expo/config-plugins/build/utils/generateCode');
const configPlugins = require('@expo/config-plugins');

const code = `  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
  $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true`;

const withReactNativeFirebase = (config) => {
  return configPlugins.withDangerousMod(config, [
    'ios',
    async (config) => {
      const filePath = path.join(
        config.modRequest.platformProjectRoot,
        'Podfile'
      );
      const contents = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf-8');

      const addCode = generateCode.mergeContents({
        tag: 'withReactNativeFirebase',
        src: contents,
        newSrc: code,
        anchor: /\s*get_default_flags\(\)/i,
        offset: 2,
        comment: '#',
      });

      if (!addCode.didMerge) {
        console.error(
          "ERROR: Cannot add withReactNativeFirebase to the project's ios/Podfile because it's malformed."
        );
        return config;
      }

      fs.writeFileSync(filePath, addCode.contents);

      return config;
    },
  ]);
};

module.exports = withReactNativeFirebase;
```

Comment: You are a hero!!! Thanks a lot!

Guys, more detailed info you can find here:
https://docs.expo.dev/guides/config-plugins/

For this answer work:
1. Create a file in the root folder for example "firebase-fix.plugin.js"
2. Specify the plugin in the app.json. In "expo.plugins" add ["./expo-plugins/firebase-fix.plugin", "custom"] to plugins array (yes, add array in the array)

Comment: thanks, add ["./expo-plugins/firebase-fix.plugin" ] in the plugin list works

Comment: I am having trouble understanding how to implement this. Is there a way to show how this looks when added to your app.config.js file? I see the comments here and have read the docs on this but am still confused how to implement and where to put this file, and what associated files/configurations are necessary.

Answer (score 8):

Finally after going through so many questions the answer was to user Flipper and modular_header in same time, finally my Pod file looks like this :-

```js
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '12.4'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

target 'MyPregnancy' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()
  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )
  
  target 'MyPregnancyTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Add this in the Pod file before the `target`

```
use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
```

This work well for React Native Application

Answer (score 4):

Add to Podfile and update pod

```
  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers =>
true
  $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
```

Answer (score 4):

I added only these 2 lines

```
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
```

Podfile (IOS)

```
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end
```

Answer (score 3):

- react 18.2.0
- react-native 0.72.6
- @react-native-firebase/app 18.7.1

Add inside your target section of Pods file:

```
target xxx
   use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
   $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
   config = use_native_modules!
```

And disable flipper

```
# :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're working on an Apple Silicon M machine with React Native version 0.73.2 and are trying to install React Native Firebase App version 18.8.0 or above while intending to keep `use_flipper` active, you might encounter some issues. Initially, you might think to include the following lines in your Podfile to address potential compatibility or library linking problems:

```rb
pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
```

However, this setup might not resolve the issue, particularly if you encounter a "library not found for -lFirebase" error during the build process.

I didn't find any Firebase static lib in the build path for the Firebase pod, or xcFrameworks either.

In my experience, simplifying the Podfile by only including the following pods can solve the problem:

```rb
pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
```

The underlying cause of this issue might be related to the transition of the Firebase pod from using static libraries to XCFrameworks.

Answer (score 1):

For native app projects, here's the [Firebase Apple SDK Release Notes (Version 9.0.0)](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#version_900_-_may_3_2022):

> CocoaPods Users
>
> **Breaking change**: Podfiles must include `use_frameworks!` or `use_frameworks! :linkage => :static`.

Just add either line in your Podfile. The difference is explained in the document: [Link Firebase dependencies statically or dynamically](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/link-firebase-static-dynamic).

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was simply because the version of the Podfile was not compatible with the new version of Firebase modules.

I am working on **React Native**, so the version of Podfile generated was not the latest one. Due to this my Firebase modules required something else in the Podfile.

It was an **easy fix to add in the Podfile**:

> use_modular_headers!

However, you can also keep an eye on the history of your packages.
I had React Native 0.69 that was released in June. I just checked the Firebase packaged version at that time and I have installed those ones.
This works as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '12.4'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

target 'SeRemo' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
  $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    # Upcoming versions of React Native may rely on get_default_flags(), but
    # we make it explicit here to aid in the React Native upgrade process.
    :hermes_enabled => true,
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    :flipper_configuration => FlipperConfiguration.enabled,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'SeRemoTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      # Set `mac_catalyst_enabled` to `true` in order to apply patches
      # necessary for Mac Catalyst builds
      :mac_catalyst_enable`enter code here`d => false
    )
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

For **REACT NATIVE EXPO**: Tested on SDK50

```
npx expo install expo-build-properties
```

and in app.json, update `expo.plugins` as

```
{
  "expo": {
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "ios": {
            "useFrameworks": "static"
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up for those desperately trying to fix this, using the newest packages, you may end up dealing with the warning "concurrency is only supported in IOS 15". That looks to be a dead end. It may be in your best interest to downgrade the package and wait for react native +70.0.

Comment: I work with react native 0.71.11 but unfortunately none of the solutions above not worked for me. -  Firebase versions:     "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^18.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^18.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^18.3.0",

Answer (score 0):

I followed [kvba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13106415/kvba) 's config plugin.
I'm forcing the FirebaseSDKVersion to 10.1.0:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const generateCode = require('@expo/config-plugins/build/utils/generateCode')
const configPlugins = require('@expo/config-plugins')

const code = `  $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true

  # Override Firebase SDK Version
  $FirebaseSDKVersion = '10.1.0'`

const withReactNativeFirebase = config => {
  return configPlugins.withDangerousMod(config, [
    'ios',
    async config => {
      const filePath = path.join(config.modRequest.platformProjectRoot, 'Podfile')
      const contents = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf-8')

      const addCode = generateCode.mergeContents({
        tag: 'withReactNativeFirebase',
        src: contents,
        newSrc: code,
        anchor: /\s*get_default_flags\(\)/i,
        offset: 2,
        comment: '#',
      })

      if (!addCode.didMerge) {
        console.error(
          "ERROR: Cannot add withReactNativeFirebase to the project's ios/Podfile because it's malformed.",
        )
        return config
      }

      fs.writeFileSync(filePath, addCode.contents)

      return config
    },
  ])
}

module.exports = withReactNativeFirebase
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when i try to use Google Tag Manager while I was using Firebase Analytics.

```yaml
  firebase_core: ^2.24.2
  firebase_analytics: ^10.7.4
```

the solution that worked for me is to add the `pod 'GoogleTagManager'` inside the `target 'Runner' do` NOT out side it.

like this:

```
target 'Runner' do
  pod 'GoogleTagManager'
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem using the steps informed in docs https://rnfirebase.io/. in step: Altering `CocoaPods` to use frameworks

first, add in `Podfile`

```
use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
```

after running the commands:

```bash
pod install --repo-update
npx expo run:ios
```

My project using:

```bash
"expo": "~49.0.18",
"react-native": "0.72.6",
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when I tried implementing the Firebase storage library into my React Native CLI project. I added the following code to the Podfile

```
  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
  $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true;
  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
```

Put above code right after the code below in the PodFile

```
target 'YourApp' do
  config = use_native_modules!
```

Answer (score 0):

The similer issue I faced with firebase version (^18.7.3). it can be any other in your case.
I added this line of code globally as it is mentioned in error:

```
use_modular_headers!
```

below these two lines at the top of podfile

```
platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!
```

and the pod installation succeed for me. The error is below

.[image: the error was some how like this as occured in this image]