# The following Swift pods cannot yet be integrated as static libraries:

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, cocoapods

I am trying to deploy my first expo project to the apple App Store but I keep getting a build error while building my app with the EAS server. Below is the detailed log report

```
[!] The following Swift pods cannot yet be integrated as static libraries:
96
The Swift pod `FirebaseCoreInternal` depends upon `GoogleUtilities`, which does not  
define modules. To opt into those targets generating module maps (which is necessary to 
import them from Swift when building as static libraries), you may set 
`use_modular_headers!` globally in your Podfile, or specify `:modular_headers => 
true` for particular dependencies.
97
The Swift pod `FirebaseStorage` depends upon 
`FirebaseAppCheckInterop`,`FirebaseAuthInterop`, `FirebaseCore`, 
`FirebaseCoreExtension`, and `GTMSessionFetcher`, which do not define modules. To 
opt into those targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import them 
from Swift when building as static libraries), you may set `use_modular_headers!` 
globally in your Podfile, or specify `:modular_headers => true` for particular dependencies.
```

according to this log I think it requires me to add some config to my `pod file` but since I'm using expo managed I have to `pod file`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift pods cannot yet be integrated as static libraries FirebaseCoreInternal-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72289521/swift-pods-cannot-yet-be-integrated-as-static-libraries-firebasecoreinternal-lib)