# React Native ios pod install error : The following Swift pods cannot yet be integrated as static libraries

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

The Swift pod `FirebaseCoreInternal` depends upon `GoogleUtilities`, which does not define modules. To opt into those targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import them from Swift when building as static libraries), you may set `use_modular_headers!` globally in your Podfile, or specify `:modular_headers => true` for particular dependencies.

[[!] The following Swift pods cannot yet be integrated as static libraries:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iMsc.png)

[package.json:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOjid.png)

Comment: can you show your `package.json`?

Comment: yes i have updated with package.json

Comment: May be this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72705219/12163469 can help you

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

I just added this 2 lines to my *`ios/podfile`*, it works for me.
Thanks.

- "react-native": "0.73.1",
- "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.8.0",
- "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^18.8.0",

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhxVL.png)